# How do I add a Client Certificate and Private Key to the Users Store in Windows with C++?

Tags: c++, windows, cryptoapi

Basically, the title: How do I add a Client Certificate and Private Key to the Users Store in Windows with C++?

I've found the function `PFXImportCertStore` which will let me load the cert and private key from a PKCS12 into a temporary cert store but I dont know how to save this store to the users store. The goal is to add a private key which other applications can access (for example, Outlook).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to call `CertAddCertificateContextToStore` to put it in the store that I wanted.

Comment: Can you explain what you did? I've tried everything under the sun, and I can't get the private key to show up in the certmgr store. If I take my crt and key and merge them into a pfx and run the windows import wizard for pfx it does exactly what I want, but I can't reproduce the effect programatically.